# Inconsistencies with RecyclerViews, ViewHolders and onBindViewHolder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I'm learning/using `RecyclerView`s and while my app works (at the moment!), there are two things that I don't understand.

Here are my ViewHolder declarations:

```
class AAAViewHolder (    view: View, var aaa: AAA? = null) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder (view) {...}
class BBBViewHolder (val view: View, var bbb: BBB? = null) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder (view) {...}
class CCCViewHolder (    view: View, var ccc: CCC? = null) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder (view) {...}
```

Why does `BBBViewHolder` have the extra `val`? If I remove it, then I get an "Unresolved reference: view" compiler error in `onBindViewHolder` in the ViewAdapter class. Why? And, if I **add* the `val`  declaration to AAA and CCC, Android Studio tells me that it's not needed and offers to remove it for me.

Next, there's something odd about the `onBindViewHolder` functions.

AAAListAdapter.kt (not showing `getItemCount` or `onCreateViewHolder`):

```
class AAAListAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<AAAViewHolder>() {
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: AAAViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val aaa = aaaList[position]
        holder.itemView.aTextView.text = "AAA"
        holder.aaa = aaa
    }
}
```

BBBListAdapter.kt

```
class BBBListAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<BBBViewHolder>() {
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BBBViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val bbb = bbbList[position]
        holder.view.bTextView.text = "BBB"
        holder.bbb = bbb
    }
}
```

CCCListAdapter.kt

```
class CCCListAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<CCCViewHolder>() {
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CCCViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val ccc = cccList[position]
        holder.itemView.cTextView.text = "CCC"
        holder.ccc = ccc
    }
}
```

The code is almost identical, except why does BBBListAdapter reference `holder.view`, while the other two reference `holder.itemView`? Where are those properties declared? Can I control that? I'd much prefer them to be the same.

Seeing how A & C act the same but B is different, I'm guessing the two questions are related, but I don't know.

Comment: Please try to remain civil here. Mutual editing is perfectly normal. For what it is worth, I thought the question was quite good, and upvoted it.

Comment: I've [created a chatroom here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217898/room-for-halfer-and-zonker-in-geneva).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you declare val/var inside constructor to use those values somewhere in class without declaring or intializing it anywhere in your class. Let take in example, i want a list in adapter I'll pass it in adapter and in adapter I won't use val/var then and I can't use that unless I create a variable before hand and initialise it inside its default constructor.

```
class A() {
      lateinit var view : View
      constructor(view : View) {
       this.view = view
      }
     view.textView.text = "Redundant Code"
}
```

Now you could have reduced this just by declaring it inside constructor itself.

```
class A(val view : View) {
      view.textView.text = "Easy way"
}
```

Now coming to your use case, viewholder A and C are identical, and B has view is declared and you are using it, but from the code in adapter I don't think it is necessary, the same logic could have been used in Adapter B, holder.itemView.something, holder.itemView is ultimately is the view object which you're using in A and C, so val view is not need for that particular case.

If you're using it somewhere, then add the whole code, there I might be able to help you out why ViewHolder B is different. But from what you have posted, there is no need for using val inside constructor.

Comment: Thank you! So simple. I removed the `val` and changed `holder.view` to `holder.itemView` and it still works. Much better, thanks.